# how can I diagnose git cat-file claiming objects are missing?

Tags: git, macos

I want to see the contents of a blob in git, but can't. What can I check?

```
$ ls -l .git/objects/25/8f90d906f3c9c9b802042d33eb13d406d60f8b
-r--r--r--  1 shauncutts  staff  2351 Jan  7 17:32 .git/objects/25/8f90d906f3c9c9b802042d33eb13d406d60f8b
$ echo .git/objects/25/8f90d906f3c9c9b802042d33eb13d406d60f8b | git cat-file --batch
.git/objects/25/8f90d906f3c9c9b802042d33eb13d406d60f8b missing
$ git --version
git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)
```

It also happens with home-brew git:

```
$ echo .git/objects/25/8f90d906f3c9c9b802042d33eb13d406d60f8b | /usr/local/bin/git cat-file --batch
.git/objects/25/8f90d906f3c9c9b802042d33eb13d406d60f8b missing
$ /usr/local/bin/git --version
git version 2.21.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object name is the hash code, not the pathname sometimes used to hold its contents.

```
git cat-file --batch <<<258f90d906f3c9c9b802042d33eb13d406d60f8b
```